# Django - Filtering object by another object

Tags: django-models

I'm looking for the solution how to filter object by another object

example:

```
def test(request):

    ranking = First.objects.filter(**user__id**=Another.objects.get(id=**user__id**).filter(HeIsVerify=True))

    return render(request, 'sth.html', {'ranking': ranking})
```

any idea to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into [Q complex queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). Try something like that :

```
ranking = First.objects.filter(Q(another__heisverify=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
First.objects.filter(user__heisverify=True)
```